# How can I stop without destroying the minecart nor using redstone?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Searching in google, found many ways to **stop** a minecart, but none of them fulfill both of these requirements:

1. Doesn't destroys the minecart (Using a cactus does so)
2. Doesn't use redstone (In Minecraft PE creative mode, cannot find it)
3. Slowing down quickly, without using lots of land (Making `S` shape non-powered track doesn't even stop it!)
4. Doesn't reverse when unsuccessful (Building a staircase going up is unsuccessful)

Therefore, any methods that can fulfill all these requirements?

** I have searched for a method like this:

```
_ _   _ _
   \ /
```

Every sign is a non-powered track. Although it said that it will slower the minecart, it doesn't. I wonder improving this method can fulfill all requirements.

Comment: Build a higher staircase? Don't make your cart go as fast beforehand? crash into a block? Do you need to start again later on, or is it just a final stop and will the cart be picked up/ moved later on?

Comment: @Jamie I have added another solution for your problem!

Comment: It's interesting that PE has powered rails, but no redstone _and_ no redstone torches. From what I can tell, they're powered as soon as you place them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X : any block (except sand, or anything that will fall
= : powered track (red)
- : non-powered track (brown)

  =   X
= X
X   - = = = =
```

Using this setting, the minecart goes from the left side to the right side. `( --> )`
The cart will crush on the block on the top, and fall on the normal rail. It's gonna stop and you can continue it again.

**Worked on Minecraft PE**

Comment: If this fixed your problem, either close the question or accept this as your accepted answer.

Comment: After two days I will do so.

Comment: Are you still waiting for another solution, or are you simply waiting?

Comment: I need two days to accept my answer. Also I want to wait for another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make a system like this:

```
[] = Powered track
{} = Unpowered track
+ = Any block 

[][][][][]{}+
```

Here is a screenshot of the setup:

[image: Setup]

This will stop the minecart no matter what, and **will not** break the minecart. This method will work if you are playing in minecraft PE. Also, it's more compact than your specified method, so it can fit into smaller places. Hope this helps!

Comment: This works. [Here's a screenshot of the setup on PE (iOS)](http://i.imgur.com/UpzCOqB.png) if you want to include it.

Comment: @Tim_Post Thanks for including the screenshot link, in fact, feel free to put it in my answer. I can't because I'm on a mobile phone.

Comment: @Tim_Post Never mind about the image.

Comment: @Jamie If my answer helped you, please accept it and/or upvote it.

Comment: This method can't really make the cart to continue. Trying my method, I can continue just __one__ brick after the break, thus it is more convenient, but it doesn't seems to be popular.

Comment: @Jamie When, and if they add detector rails and pistons, you could create a setup like that.

Comment: But using my setup, I can do so! See my edit (in 2~3 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

what do you thingk of making an circel from 2x2 tracks at the end. you will ride on the track and just start slowing down. in the end you will stop and just use a 2x2 area for it.

> x   x
>
> x   x

every x is a track seen from above.

Answer (score -2):

Cobwebs on a corner will stop you

From above

----------*
         *----------